# A virtual screen on Windows 7 that's always on?

Tags: windows-7, windows, display

Perhaps someone has encountered a similar situation and has a solution. Is there a way to have a virtual screen on a system (like a mirror driver that a VNC client might use, like DFMirage), but that stays on all the time, not just when a remote connection is active.

Basically I have a piece of software that only sends output to second screen on a system where there's only one physical output. If I connect remotely and a virtual screen is established it works, If I disconnect it doesn't.

Comment: Do you have a spare VGA or DVI-I output? I've heard of people making dummy monitor plugs for things like GPGPU work

Comment: Unfortunately not - it's a small form factor PC with a single HDMI output.

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922174/creating-a-virtual-monitor-the-display-device